# Insert a list of objects in the local base, Room

Tags: android

I have the CidVo class:

```
@Entity
public class CidVo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6128323407787450445L;

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    private String idCid;

    private String dsCid;
    //private StatusType idStatus;

    public CidVo() {
        super();
    }

    public String getIdCid() {
        return idCid;
    }

    public void setIdCid(String idCid) {
        this.idCid = idCid;
    }

    public String getDsCid() {
        return dsCid;
    }

    public void setDsCid(String dsCid) {
        this.dsCid = dsCid;
    }

    /*public StatusType getIdStatus() {
        return idStatus;
    }

    public void setIdStatus(StatusType idStatus) {
        this.idStatus = idStatus;
    } */

}
```

The DAO class:

```
@Dao
public interface CIDDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAllCID(ArrayList<CidVo>... cidVos);
}
```

I get a list of objects, via JSON. And I would like to save it in the database.
But, I get this return error when trying to compile:

> Error:Entity class must be annotated with @Entity
>   E:\workspace_android_studio\app_atendimento_branch_test\app\src\main\java\br\com\sisteplan\app\atendimento\Model\CIDDao.java
>   Error:(19, 43) error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated
>   with @Entity or a collection/array of it.

How to solve this question?
The following is the postExecute:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<Retorno> respAtestadoVo) {
        super.onPostExecute(respAtestadoVo);
        if (respAtestadoVo.getExceptionResult() == null) {
            RetornoCid retornoCid = (RetornoCid) respAtestadoVo.getResult();
            ArrayList<CidVo> cidVos = (ArrayList<CidVo>) retornoCid.getRetorno();

            appDataBase.getCidDao().insertAllCID(cidVos);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Instance:

```
@Database(entities = {CidVo.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDataBase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract CIDDao getCidDao();

    private static AppDataBase appDataBase;

    public static AppDataBase getInstance(Context context){
        if(null == appDataBase){
            appDataBase = buildDataBaseInstance(context);
        }
        return appDataBase;
    }

    private static AppDataBase buildDataBaseInstance(Context context){
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDataBase.class,
                "app_database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }

    private void cleanUp(){
        appDataBase = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is a vararg notation here `void insertAllCID(ArrayList<CidVo>... cidVos);`
You're trying to insert an array of array lists.
So, just replace it with

```
void insertAllCID(List<CidVo> cidVos);
```

Also, it's better to use interfaces over implementations, when you're working with collections. So, you can change this part

```
RetornoCid retornoCid = (RetornoCid) respAtestadoVo.getResult();
ArrayList<CidVo> cidVos = (ArrayList<CidVo>) retornoCid.getRetorno();
```

to this

```
RetornoCid retornoCid = (RetornoCid) respAtestadoVo.getResult();
List<CidVo> cidVos = new ArrayList(retornoCid.getRetorno());
```